# Resource links within a web view?

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to include resource links (i.e., res://...) within a web view?  My attempts so far suggest not. I can include standard  tags and reference local files, but those are not scaled for the various display densities.

Answer (score 1):

`res://` is the format that only the NativeScript's file system would understand, more like a custom shorthand.

If you have the image inside Android's drawable folder, you may try this

```
file:///android_res/drawable/YOUR_FILE_NAME
```

For iOS, you will have to load it with absolute path.

Comment: So, the answer is, "No."  Makes sense.